# Como fazer foreign key um-para-muitos no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela alunos e uma tabela cursos, minha tabela cursos tem o curso por exemplo de administração, como eu relaciono vários aluno a essa tabela usando Foreign key ?

Comment: Não tenho muita experiencia em sql, mas normalmente cria-se uma terceira tabela... ex: `aluno_curso`, aonde um aluno pode se matricular em mais de um curso e um curso pode ter vários alunos matriculados. Essa tabela, teria basicamente um id, idaluno, idcurso. Eu faria desta forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você cria a Tabela CURSOS com a coluna ID_CURSOS (PRIMARY_KEY), depois você cria uma tabela ALUNOS com a coluna ID_ALUNOS (primary_key) e a coluna ID_CURSO. Esta coluna ID_CURSO você aponta como FOREIGN_KEY tendo como referência a tabela CURSOS, coluna ID_CURSOS. Segue exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`cursos` (
  `id_cursos` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_curso` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cursos`));


CREATE TABLE `database`.`alunos` (
  `id_alunos` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_curso` INT NULL,
  `nome_aluno` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_alunos`),
  INDEX `FK_ALUNO_CURSO_idx` (`id_curso` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ALUNO_CURSO` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_curso`) 
    REFERENCES `vigilant`.`cursos` (`id_cursos`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Qualquer dúvida só falar.
Abraços.

Comment: Entendi, como eu coloco as unidades curriculares(modulos) associado com o nome do curso ? os modulos são uma lista como eu faria para criar esse modulo, seria uma tabela para cada modulo ?

Comment: Desculpa, mas não entendi. Explica direito o que são módulos. São as matérias do curso? Deixa ver se entendi. Exemplo: Curso de Administração (Módulo I: matéria 1, matéria 2, matéria 3; Módulo II: matéria 4, matéria 5, matéria 6). É isso?

Comment: Caso seja da forma como entendi, terá que criar uma tabela MÓDULOS e criar uma FOREIGN_KEY referenciando para o ID_CURSO da tabela CURSOS. Ou seja, através disso, você estará ligando módulos a cada curso.

Comment: Os relacionamentos em DB são feitos através das FKs. Você tem relacionamento 1 para 1 (1:1); 1 para N (1:N); e N para N (N:N). Isto é, relacionamento 1:1 é quando uma tabela está relacionada a outra, mas cada registro aponta apenas a outro de outra tabela; o 1:N é quando um registro de uma tabela se relaciona a vários outros de outra tabela; e N:N é quando vários registros de uma tabela se relaciona a vários registros de outra tabela. Este último, para ser implementado, deve-se criar uma terceira tabela para criar o relacionamento de vários para vários. Exemplo é o que está na resposta acima.